# Code smell when recursively returning a List

Tags: java, recursion, tree

So this is part of my AVL tree implementation, namely the infix representation of the tree. Since I wanted to use a recursive method to stay close to the original algorithm and want to return a list, I have to store the values in a parameter.

The smelly part is in getInfix when I reference that parameter to return the list. I am not even sure what's the name of this code smell but it feels wrong. I am literally only calling getInfixInternal for its side effect! But I can't simply return a list either...

How can I make this better?

```
private List<T> getInfix() {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    getInfixInternal(root, result);
    return result;
}

private void getInfixInternal(Node node, List<T> infixValues) {
    if (node != null) {
        getInfixInternal(node.getLeft(), infixValues);
        infixValues.add((T) node.getValue());
        getInfixInternal(node.getRight(), infixValues);
    }
}
```

My Node class (excluding the getters and setters for reasons of space):

```
public class Node <T extends Comparable>  {
    private T value;
    private Node leftChild;
    private Node rightChild;
    private Node parent;
}
```

Comment: Recursion is itself a code smell

Comment: @BradThomas that statement is possibly the most offensive and stupid statement about programming that I heard in months. Congratulations. Recursion is a standard approach for method / function behaviour in **all** languages

Comment: "Standard" means nothing. Bad practice is also "standard" across the industry, in all languages. I have never come across a meaningful use of recursion (outside of academic interest) that could not be more readably and maintainably coded without the use of recursion.

Comment: @Brad Thomas care to elaborate? I have read similar in the power of ten rules but cant really follow the Argumentation

Comment: Recursion is used for the sake of purported brevity, elegance but has a heavy cost in terms of readability and maintainability. I'm not saying it's never the most appropriate solution, only that I believe it is widely over-used for most line-of-business applications. In contrast to academic study questions, these applications are often in service over many years and require considerable ongoing maintenance. IMO a simpler flat enumeration over the tree would often suffice and be easier to analyze and maintain in most cases. Being widely over-used makes it a code smell i.e. likely inappropriate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is a code smell with what you have now. However, it could be made more OOP-friendly.

An actual problem is that you're using raw types for `Node`, and that is [never a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). So, first of all, consider having this instead:

```
private List<T> getInfix() {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    getInfixInternal(root, result);
    return result;
}

private void getInfixInternal(Node<T> node, List<T> infixValues) {
    if (node != null) {
        getInfixInternal(node.getLeft(), infixValues);
        infixValues.add(node.getValue());
        getInfixInternal(node.getRight(), infixValues);
    }
}
```

[and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779184/explanation-of-generic-t-extends-comparable-super-t-in-collection-sort-com)

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Then, to avoid this `getInfixInternal`, you can reason with what the method `getInfix` means. The first thing to realize is that it works on a given `Node`. In fact, it is really a property of the node itself: every node can return a list of values resulting of a infix traversal of the subtree starting at this node. Therefore, instead of having an internal method taking a `Node` as parameter, make it a method of `Node`:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    // ...

    public List<T> getInfix() {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (leftChild != null) {
            result.addAll(leftChild.getInfix());
        }
        result.add(value);
        if (rightChild != null) {
            result.addAll(rightChild.getInfix());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

With such a method, you can then have:

```
private List<T> getInfix() {
    return root == null ? Collections.emptyList() : root.getInfix();
}
```

With Java 8 [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), you could potentially write that more concisely:

```
public List<T> getInfix() {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Optional.ofNullable(leftChild).map(Node::getInfix).ifPresent(result::addAll);
    result.add(value);
    Optional.ofNullable(rightChild).map(Node::getInfix).ifPresent(result::addAll);
    return result;
}
```

Final note: you could also consider returning unmodifiable lists.

Comment: Note that the modified version where you shift it to the node allocates a list for each node which is pretty wasteful

Comment: @WorldSEnder Any idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: @Tunaki Really good points, I thought about the infix being a Node function as well!